# Reversing a BOOL

Tags: objective-c, boolean

In objective-c, if I wanted to reverse the value of a `BOOL`, would this work, or would it set the value of the `BOOL` to `NO`?

```
BOOL ab = YES;

ab = !ab; // would this reverse the BOOL, ab, and set it to NO?

if (ab == NO) {
    ab = !ab; // would this reverse the BOOL again and set it to YES?
}
```

Comment: Yes and yes. In fact, it's easier to compile and take a look rather than post a question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that will work. `BOOL` is just an integer. `YES` is `1` and `NO` is `0`. `!1 == 0` and `!0 == 1`.

Comment: to clarify: technically a BOOL is a signed char, not an int

Answer (score 2):

quick question, quick answer.
yes

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL`s work exactly as you have described. Not that `NO` is `0` and `YES` is equal to anything else (except `NULL`).

Examples:

1. !YES == NO
2. !NO == YES
3. !1 == NO
4. !0 == YES
5. !5 == NO

Answer (score 0):

These are correct!

1. !YES == NO
2. !NO == YES
3. !1 == NO
4. !0 == YES
5. !5 == NO

This is not correct!

FreeAsInBeer: "YES is equal to anything else (except NULL)." - NOT TRUE

YES equals to nothing but the signed char 1, so YES == 32626 for instance returns false!!